# connection timeout accessing server from specific network

Tags: linux, networking, router, ssh, vpn

My server at home (Pi Zero - Stretch) used for general maintenance when I'm away.

I can ssh and vpn into the server from mobile and laptop on wifi pretty much anywhere in the world / country, however today I had to do it from my work pc on company network (for the first time) and neither the ssh via powershell or my vpn succeeded to connect, neither if I use wifi on my mobile, but when i turn off wifi and uses 4G it works like a charm.

When i try to just ping my public ip it times out, when i try to log into my router via https, I can't get a connexion.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this? can the IT guys possibly block all traffic going to my public ip?

Best regards.

Comment: What are the both ISPs? Have you asked your company sysadmins about this? Does the company network allow outgoing SSH access in general?

Comment: Company ISP: TDC Bredbaand Professional Users.
Home ISP: Fullrate DK Customers.

As we use an external It guy, I would need to call them and as soon as i do, we get billed..

It seems that both SSH and VPN is blocked, and the inability to ping could be explained with a Ping-block on the router, however i cant seem to understand how the access to my routers login page (port 8080) can be blocked?

Comment: Perhaps they block everything _except_ pre-approved services (DNS/HTTP/HTTPS).